# Изменить шрифт в TeX с сохранением оформления для окружений theorem, lemma, etc

Tags: шрифты, latex

Может ли кто-то помочь со следующей проблемой в TeX: когда меняю шрифт в преамбуле документа, то скидываются настройки для окружений theorem, lemma и т.д.? Они становятся без выделения жирным шрифтом и курсивом. Согласно требованиям должен быть шрифт Times New Roman и собирать нужно с помощью PdfLaTeX.

Привожу MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, top=2cm, right=1cm, bottom=20mm, nohead, nofoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{times} % Times New Roman
%\usepackage{mathptmx,etoolbox}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\setcounter{page}{2}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

%\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheoremstyle{note}% hnamei
{3pt}% hSpace abovei
{3pt}% hSpace belowi
{}% hBody fonti
{}% hIndent amounti
{\itshape}% hTheorem head fonti
{:}% hPunctuation after theorem headi
{.5em}% hSpace after theorem headi
{}% hTheorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)


\newtheorem{theorem}{Теорем}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Лемма}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Текст текст текст. Текст который должен быть курсивом. Текст текст
текст текст.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
Текст текст текст текст. Слово лемма должно быть выделено жирным.
текст текст текст.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Что получается после сборки в PdfLaTeX

[image: Что получается после сборки в PdfLaTeX]

Нашел в Интернете способ менять оформление окружения theorem:

```
\newtheoremstyle{note}% hnamei
{3pt}% hSpace abovei
{3pt}% hSpace belowi
{}% hBody fonti
{}% hIndent amounti
{\itshape}% hTheorem head fonti
{:}% hPunctuation after theorem headi
{.5em}% hSpace after theorem headi
{}% hTheorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
```

Но после добавления этих строчек никаких изменений не происходит.

Если удалить строчку:

```
\usepackage{times} % Times New Roman
```

то оформление окружений theorem, lemma верное, но шрифт не тот.

Можно ли добиться желаемого в рамках PdfLaTeX?

P.S.: в TeX я новичок.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, то что Вы привели не совсем MWE - его нельзя просто скопипастить, скомпилировать и увидеть проблему, потому как это просто преамбула с кучей лишних пакетов (которые не влияют на проблему). И нет самого тела документа.

Все дело в том, что гарнитуру *Times New Roman* просто так использовать не получится - нужен огромный бубен по конвертированию шрифта типа TTF в шрифт Type 1. Но можно использовать похожий по начертанию шрифт (да, *Adobe Times* был создан раньше *Times New Roman*, поэтому последний - это всего лишь копия оригинала). В LaTeX есть шрифт *times* (кажется, это реализация от URW, а не от Adobe), но с ним есть небольшая проблема - у него нет кириллицы. Совсем. Поэтому Вы и получили отсутствие жирного и курсива, и много чего еще (вплоть до капители). Если бы Вы посмотрели внимательнее, tex подменяет не найденные символы шрифта на стандартный *cmr* (Computer Modern Roman).

Выход - найти шрифт, наиболее близкий к начертанию Times, который содержит и кириллицу. Например, можно использовать шрифт (и одноименный пакет) *tempora*.
В нем есть почти все необходимые модификации шрифта, кроме Small Caps (`\textsc{}`, капитель). Также, хорошо бы по плотности подобрать этому шрифту в комплект начертание Sans (версия шрифта без засечек... ну было бы странно, если бы у таймса был свой вариант :-)) и Teletype (моноширинный, тоже задается отдельным пакетом). Если отдельно эти начертания не задавать, то tex будет использовать стандартные *cmss* и *cmtt*, соответственно (ну, может Вам и они подойдут).

С математическим шрифтом - почти такая же проблема (ему кириллица не нужна, но нужна реализация всех математических символов). Какие проблемы у шрифта *mathptmx* я уже точно не помню - кажется он довольно конфликтный с окружающими шрифтами. Я обычно использую более модный сейчас *newtxmath*.

В примере, я использую комплект:

```
\usepackage{tempora}                        % Times New Roman for text
\usepackage[bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath}    % math italic letters from Nimbus Roman
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}         % mathcal from STIX, unslanted a bit
```

*Важное замечание*: математические шрифты обычно немного конфликтуют с amsfonts, потому что в ams переопределяются некоторые команды. В общем, чтобы не разбираться с этими мелкими конфликтами (там значки интегралов по замкнутому контуру и пара букв с полым жирным начертанием, если правильно помню) достаточно загружать пакеты в определенном порядке: сначала пакеты ams, а уже потом математические шрифты (но удобнее все шрифты держать рядом).

Последний шрифт задает в математике каллиграфическое начертание. Его можно не использовать, а обойтись стандартным из набора AMS-расширений, но у этого есть строчные буквы, в отличие от стандартного.

Далее, если Вы хотите использовать свой стиль для теорем - его мало определить, его надо еще и сделать активным для Ваших объявления теорем (строчка: `\theoremstyle{note}` в примере). Сам стиль Вы задали странно, я его подправил. Да и вообще, возможно, он Вам и не понадобится, а хватит и предлагаемых стилей в AMS-расширениях (plain и все остальные).

Далее, сам исправленный пример (тексты теорем/лемм честно стащены в интернете и за их справедливость ответственности не несу :-) ):

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, top=2cm, right=1cm, bottom=20mm, nohead, nofoot]{geometry}

%\usepackage{times} % Times New Roman
%\usepackage{mathptmx,etoolbox}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{tempora}                        % Times New Roman for text
\usepackage[bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath}    % math italic letters from Nimbus Roman
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}         % mathcal from STIX, unslanted a bit

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\setcounter{page}{2}

%\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheoremstyle{note}% hnamei
{3pt}% hSpace abovei
{3pt}% hSpace belowi
{\itshape}% hBody fonti
{}% hIndent amounti
{\bfseries}% hTheorem head fonti
{:}% hPunctuation after theorem headi
{.5em}% hSpace after theorem headi
{}% hTheorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{note}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Теорем}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Лемма}

\newcommand{\abc}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\newcommand{\ABC}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}[Wolfenstein, 1572]
        People have fun with beer.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{lemma}[Рукопожатия]
        В каждом конечном неориентированном графе число вершин, которые касаются нечетного числа ребер, является четным.
    \end{lemma}

    \begin{theorem}
        Сумма углов треугольника
        равна $180^{\circ}$.
    \end{theorem}

    \[
    I = \iint\limits_{G}{z\sqrt{1 + z_{x}^{2} + z_{y}^{2}}} \, dx \, dy =
    \iint\limits_{G}{xy\sqrt{1+y^{2}+x^{2}}}
    \, dx \, dy,
    \]
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [math normal:]    $\abc$\\ $\ABC$
        \item [math upright:]   $\mathrm{\abc}$\\ $\mathrm{\ABC}$
        \item [math italic:]    $\mathit{\abc}$\\ $\mathit{\ABC}$
        \item [math bold:]      $\mathbf{\abc}$\\ $\mathbf{\ABC}$
        \item [math cal:]       $\mathcal{\abc}$\\ $\mathcal{\ABC}$
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Также я добавил вывод алфавита разными начертаниями в математической моде, чтобы было видно как выглядят буквы (должны быть похожи на коммерческий шрифт *Adobe MathTimePro*, ну и на *Times* (в нашем случае, *tempora*) в тексте - соответственно тоже).

На выходе у меня получился документ такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И внизу окна видно какие шрифты были реально использованы. Хотя, наверное, на глаз тоже можно отличить *times* от стандартного *cmr* (*times* выглядит более плотным).

Comment: Спасибо огромное за подробный ответ! Похоже. что действительно в рамках PdfLaTex то, что мне нужно не сделать. Только ухищрения, которые вы предлагаете, "выглядящие почти как нужно". Но, всё равно, еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @innokentijglum, это не ухищрения. В нормальных вузах эти шрифты нормально проходят даже для защит кандидатских и докторских диссертаций. И я уверен, что люди, которые требуют именно Times New Roman не смогут его отличить от Times или других его реализаций в latex. Но если уж Вам так нужно именно Times New Roman, то можете его использовать в XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.